# ASP.NET MVC Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have 300,000+ rows, when I test my project the Datatable is loading for about 30sec then this error occured

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

[image: Error]

btw I am using Jquery Datatables, this is my code:

HomeController.cs:

```
public JsonResult GetAllRecords()
{
    var records = GetRecords().ToList();
    return Json(new { data = records }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var FilterSAR = $('#RecordsDatatable').DataTable({
"ajax": {
    "url": '/Home/GetAllRecords',
    "type": "get",
    "datatype": "json"
},
"columns": [
    { "data": "ssn_or_tin", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "cusid", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "accountNo", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "dateTrans", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "transCode", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "transdescription", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "amount", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "cashin", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "cashout", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "source", "autoWidth": true }
]
});
```

Index.chtml

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="RecordsDatatable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>SSN or TIN</th>
    <th>Customer ID</th>
    <th>Account Number</th>
    <th>Date Transaction</th>
    <th>Trans Code</th>
    <th>Trans Description</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Cash in</th>
    <th>Cash out</th>
    <th>Source</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Then i searched for solutions online and i found this code:

```
public JsonResult GetAllRecords()
{
    var jsonResult = Json(GetRecords().ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return jsonResult;
}
```

[image: Error gone but still not working]

The error is gone but my records are still not showing, i think it has something to do with the Json code, I also found other solution like the Serialize but i can't seem to make it work with my code maybe because i am using JsonResult not ContentResult, I'm not sure.

Comment: Your screenshot shows one error, is that a related error?

Comment: What is that error in your console?

Comment: @CodingYoshi no, it's not related, i can get rid of that error if i want to, but still my records are not showing even if there are no errors.

Comment: In the network tab, does the response show any data returning from the server?

Comment: @CodingYoshi In the screenshot im in the network tab, where can i see the response?

Comment: double-click the `GetAllRecords` and it will show more details about it. You can see the request and response there.

Comment: @CodingYoshi im getting "Failed to load response data"

Answer (score 3):

In HomeController.cs use this

**return new JsonResult() { Data = result, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };**

instead of

*return Json(new { data = records }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);*